# :extend() in nested block

Tags: css, less

This code:

```
.first {
    margin: 19px;

    .nested {
        color: white;
    }
}

.second:extend(.first) {
}
```

outputs:

```
.first,
.second {
  margin: 19px;
}
.first .nested {
  color: white;
}
```

But if you wrap it in another block:

```
div {
    .first {
        margin: 19px;

        .nested {
            color: white;
        }
    }

    .second:extend(.first) {
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
div .first {
  margin: 19px;
}
div .first .nested {
  color: white;
}
```

disregards extend? Is this a bug?

Comment: No, it's not a bug. `extend` is not relative to the selector it's used with, `extend` always requires complete ("absolute") selector "path". I.e. it should be `.second:extend(div .first)` no matter where the `.second` itself is located.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Can you please post it as answer. I will approve it. :)

Comment: Try to describe the problem more specifically in the title of your question.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2101) feature request says ready for implementation but not sure about the release. If and when it gets implemented, the `any` match might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921925/extend-in-nested-block/27029346#comment42391866_26921925) above by [@seven-phases-max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2712740/seven-phases-max)

No, it's not a bug. `:extend` is not relative to the selector it's used with; it always requires a complete ("absolute") selector "path". I.e. it should be `.second:extend(div .first)` no matter where the `.second` itself is located.

```
div {
    .first {
        margin: 19px;

        .nested {
            color: white;
        }
    }
    .second:extend(div .first) {}
}
```